# Java - How to send notification from server to client

Tags: java, server-push

> I am having a server where my **java
>   web application** and **database
>   server** reside.
>
> Now the clients of my **web app** are
>   of two types:
>
> - ClientType1
> - ClientType2
>
> Both can access the database.
>
> **ClientType1** stores the data in the database.
>
> **ClientType2** retrieves the data from the database.
>
> But the **ClientType1** should start
>   storing the data in the database
>   when the **ClientType2** says
>   **Start**.
>
> Similarily **ClientType1** should stop storing the data in the database
>   when the **ClientType2** says **Stop**

===========================================================================

**Q1.** What are the solutions for this problem?

- Here are the approaches I thought of:
- Create a table in the database having one column that shows the status **Start** or **Stop** and this column's value should be set by **ClientType2**. **ClientType1** will keep sending the query to the database for getting the status from this table and perform operations according to the status.
- Apply **[ServerPush](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch06_03.htm)** approach by which the server will keep a connection with the **ClientType1** alive and will send the request to him whenever it receives the command (**Start** or **Stop**) from the **ClientType2**. Problem with this approach is that the no. of open sockets at the sever will increase as the increase in the no. of **ClientType1**

Answer (score 0):

I don't really consider interprocess communication through a database to be a great approach. The typical scenario is that the client registers itself with the server making it eligible for receiving messages using a socket-based mechanism.

The client can then either:

- Ask the server to perform a database operation on behalf of it
- Request access to the database

If there are that many clients that keeping an open connection will be a problem you could either initiate a new connection every time you need to communicate with the server or let the server offer e.g., some kind of REST API which the server can poll.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "client registers itself with the server".

Comment: @Yatendra, that is the *client* initiates contact to the *server* which can keep a queue of all *clients*. This queue can be used to arbitrate database access between the clients. E.g., the servern can send `start` and `stop` commands to the clients in the queue in turn. In short you can apply the `Listener` concept over the network.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a kind of Ajax for this since this abstracts the "server can call client" away.

Choose a library that allows you to keep a single connection open and do multiple things through this connection.

Comment: I think that a single open connection can serve only to one client. So for many clients, the server needs to keep open various connections (sockets) which won't work in case we have lots of clients.

Comment: Naturally each client needs its own connection.  That is how TCP/IP works.  For the "many clients" scenario you will need to use an underlying web server which is tuned for this kind of usage - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem - here is the primary Jetty developers comment on the issue. http://markmail.org/message/ulfklgftht7lhcqu